# After installing Ubuntu the Broadcom network adapter is not functioning. How can I fix this?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on an old Acer Aspire 3680 last night. Previous to the install everything worked fine. I was able to connect to Wifi. Since the install I have not been able to.

All I have done so far is this:

- run software updates
- opened terminal and ran `lspci`,  which tells me that I have a Broadcom BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)

Then I ran `sudo lshw -C network`. This is the output:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8038 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 14
       serial: 00:1b:24:4f:f0:2c
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 memory:44000000-44003fff ioport:2000(size=256)
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=wl latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:44500000-44503fff
```

I than ran `rfkill list all`.  output:

```
0: acer-wireless: wireless LAN
soft blocked: no
hard blocked: no
```

At this point I'm thinking I'm just missing a driver,  easy fix. But just to cover my bases I ran `lsmod | grep acer`. output:

```
acer_wmi               31735  0 
sparse_keymap          13708  1 acer_wmi
wmi                    18673  1 acer_wmi
video                  18903  2 i915,acer_wmi
```

After checking the support site I came to find 2 possible drivers. I first tried installing `linux-firmware-nonfree` driver and rebooting.  I was still unable to connect.  when running the `rfkill list all` command it now showed soft blocked: yes.

At this point I reinstalled the OS preformed all of the aforementioned steps but this time installed the `firmware-b43-installer`.  Now again after running the `rfkill list all` command I am once again soft blocked.

I am stuck. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: you can disable broadcom drivers and restart and install non-free driver and restart.non-free driver here:sudo apt-get install linux-firmware linux-firmware-nonfree

Answer (score 1):

You needn't blacklist acer-wmi.

Please get a temporary internet connection and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: thank you very much...  I tried it before you added the sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source line and nothing..  But now,  I am up and running!  chili555,  u rock!

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following command will fix it but if not then post the output from the script that I asked for.

```
echo "blacklist acer-wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot